# Double for-loop operation in R (with an example)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

Please look at the following small working example:

```
#### Pseudo data
nobs1 <- 4000
nobs2 <- 5000
mylon1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)+37
mylon2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)+37

#### define a distance function
thedistance <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
 R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]
 delta.lon <- (lon2 - lon1)
 delta.lat <- (lat2 - lat1)
 a <- sin(delta.lat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(delta.lon/2)^2
 c <- 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt(a)))
 d = R * c
 return(d)
}

ptm <- proc.time()

#### Calculate distances between locations
# Initiate the resulting distance vector
ndistance <- nobs1*nobs2 # The number of distances
mydistance <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = ndistance)

k=1
for (i in 1:nobs1) {
 for (j in 1:nobs2) {
  mydistance[k] = thedistance(mylon1[i],mylat1[i],mylon2[j],mylat2[j])
  k=k+1
 }
}

proc.time() - ptm
```

The computation time:

```
  user  system elapsed 
249.85    0.16  251.18
```

Here, my question is whether there is still room for speeding up the double for-loop calculation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why 4000 and 5000 observations?

Comment: They are just randomly chosen for the illustration.

Comment: OK but should they necessarily be different numbers?

Comment: Oh. Those should be different for my original problem. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I think you can use one of the apply family functions to speed up your solution, however it requires a matrix or a data.frame wirh all possible combinations of distances. I have written a solution with the apply function, however the construction of the combined data.frame takes forever.

Comment: The most important fact I've learnt about R is that 'if you're using a for-loop you're probably doing it wrong'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an option that decreases the runtime to ~2 seconds on my machine because part of it is vectorized.

A direct comparison with the original solution follows.

Test data:

```
nobs1 <- 4000
nobs2 <- 5000
mylon1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)+37
mylon2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)+37
```

Original solution:

```
#### define a distance function
thedistance <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]
  delta.lon <- (lon2 - lon1)
  delta.lat <- (lat2 - lat1)
  a <- sin(delta.lat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(delta.lon/2)^2
  c <- 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt(a)))
  d = R * c
  return(d)
}

ptm <- proc.time()

#### Calculate distances between locations
# Initiate the resulting distance vector
ndistance <- nobs1*nobs2 # The number of distances
mydistance <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = ndistance)

k=1
for (i in 1:nobs1) {
  for (j in 1:nobs2) {
    mydistance[k] = thedistance(mylon1[i],mylat1[i],mylon2[j],mylat2[j])
    k=k+1
  }
}

proc.time() - ptm
   User      System     elapsed 
148.243       0.681     148.901
```

My approach:

```
# modified (vectorized) distance function:
thedistance2 <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]
  delta.lon <- (lon2 - lon1)
  delta.lat <- (lat2 - lat1)
  a <- sin(delta.lat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(delta.lon/2)^2
  c <- 2 * asin(pmin(1,sqrt(a)))   # pmin instead of min
  d = R * c
  return(d)
}

ptm2 <- proc.time()

lst <- vector("list", length = nobs1)

for (i in seq_len(nobs1)) {
    lst[[i]] = thedistance2(mylon1[i],mylat1[i],mylon2,mylat2)
}

res <- unlist(lst)

proc.time() - ptm2
   User      System     elapsed
  1.988       0.331       2.319
```

Are the results all equal?

```
all.equal(mydistance, res)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: well that's beautiful.

Comment: Simply amazing. By the way, would you let me know your laptop/desktop's hardware spec? The elapsed time of mine was 7.05 following your approach.

Comment: mine is also 7 sec. I curious too.

Comment: Here: Lenovo ThinkPad x230 i3-3120M 16GB RAM with a SSD SATA III

Comment: Mac...the undeniable killer machine.

Comment: One more tiny improvement you could make: put `R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]` outside the distance function so that it's not repeated in each loop (doesnt change).

Comment: Take out `return` and see if that makes any difference.  In fact the second to last line could be the last line

Comment: Are you able to test/benchmark my fully vectorised solution as my laptop can't handle large matrices?

Comment: I can't currently test it. But as it currently stands, it's not fully vectorized since you use sapply twice (which is essentially a for loop). On the other hand, I think those sapply's are not necessary since you are just subtracting vectors. Maybe better double check it. @tospig

Comment: Ah right. The vectors are different lengths though so I didn't think they could simply be subtracted?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other approach using `Rcpp`. On my machine it was slightly faster than beginneR's very nice vectorized version.

```
library(Rcpp)

nobs1 <- 4000
nobs2 <- 5000
mylon1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)+37
mylon2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)+37

sourceCpp("dist.cpp")

system.time({
  lst <- vector("list", length = nobs1)
  for (i in seq_len(nobs1)) {
    lst[[i]] = thedistance2(mylon1[i],mylat1[i],mylon2,mylat2)
  }
  res <- unlist(lst)
})

##  user  system elapsed 
## 4.636   0.084   4.737 


system.time(res2 <- dist_vec(mylon1, mylat1, mylon2, mylat2))
##  user  system elapsed 
## 2.584   0.044   2.633 

all.equal(res, res2)
## TRUE
```

And the file `dist.cpp` countains

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

double dist_cpp(double lon1, double lat1,
                double lon2, double lat2){
  int R = 6371; 
  double delta_lon = (lon2 - lon1);
  double delta_lat = (lat2 - lat1);
  double a = pow(sin(delta_lat/2.0), 2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(sin(delta_lon/2.0), 2);
  double c;
  a = sqrt(a);
  if (a < 1.0) {
    c = 2 * asin(a);
  } else {
    c = 2 * asin(1);
  }
  double d = R * c;
  return(d);

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector dist_vec(NumericVector lon1, NumericVector lat1, 
                       NumericVector lon2, NumericVector lat2) {
  int n = lon1.size();
  int m = lon2.size();
  int k = n * m;
  NumericVector res(k);
  int c = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      res[c] = dist_cpp(lon1[i], lat1[i], lon2[j], lat2[j]);
      c++;
    }
  }
  return(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran this 3 times, once as you have here, once loading up library `compiler` (in base R) and running `enableJIT(3)`, and running (with `enableJIT`) after compiling your `thedistance` function with `cmpfun()` (in `compiler`). The results are (respectively):

```
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
 335.26    0.17  339.83

> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
 120.73    0.12  122.52 

> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
 117.86    0.12  118.95
```

The difference with 2 and 3 is neglible, as I think `enableJIT` just compiles the function anyway, but it looks like there is a decent improvement with `enableJIT` alone. so just throw

```
library(compiler)
```

`enableJIT(3)`

at the top of your code.

More information can be found [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/04/speed-up-your-r-code-using-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler/)

Comment: Thanks. Now the elapsed time is 110.22 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(compiler)
enableJIT(3)

nobs1 <- 4000
nobs2 <- 4000
mylon1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat1 <- runif(nobs1, min=0, max=1)+37
mylon2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)-76
mylat2 <- runif(nobs2, min=0, max=1)+37

trixie<-matrix(nrow=length(mylon1),ncol=4)
trixie[,1]<-mylon1
trixie[,2]<-mylat1
trixie[,3]<-mylon2
trixie[,4]<-mylat2

#### define a distance function
thedistance <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]
  delta.lon <- (lon2 - lon1)
  delta.lat <- (lat2 - lat1)
  a <- sin(delta.lat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(delta.lon/2)^2
  c <- 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt(a)))
  d = R * c
  return(d)
}
calc_distance <- cmpfun(thedistance)
ptm <- proc.time()

#### Calculate distances between locations
# Initiate the resulting distance vector
distances<-apply(trixie,1, function(x) {
  return(apply(trixie,1, function(y) {
    return(calc_distance(x[1],x[2],y[3],y[4]))
  }))
})

proc.time() - ptm
```

Comment: The OP in the comments wants nobs1 different from nobs2. So its a combination of all possible nobs1 and nobs2. So instead of 4000 combinations the OP requires 4000*5000 combinations. Thats why its under a second in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, one is partly vectorised that uses `sapply`, and I think the other is fully vectorised, but I've written a couple of functions for part of the vector calculations so there may be a better way.

I also only ran these for `nobs1 = 4, 40 & 400` and `nobs2 = 5, 50 & 500` as my laptop struggles for memory with `large matrices`.

**Solution - sapply**

```
R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]

delta.lon <- sapply(mylon2, "-", mylon1)
delta.lon <- sin(delta.lon/2)^2

coslat2 <- cos(mylat2)
coslat1 <- cos(mylat1)

delta.lan <- sapply(mylat2, "-", mylat1)
delta.lan <- sin(delta.lan/2)^2

a <- delta.lan + t(sapply(coslat1, "*", coslat2) * t(delta.lon))
b <- ifelse(sqrt(a)<1,sqrt(a),1)
c <- asin(b)
d <- 2 * c
e <- R * d

f <- c(t(e))
```

And to check the output

```
sum(f)
sum(mydistance)

all.equal(f, mydistance)


> sum(f)
[1] 647328856
> sum(mydistance)
[1] 647328856
> all.equal(f, mydistance)
[1] TRUE
```

**Solution - with functions**

```
R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]

#function to calculate the difference between each
#element of different sized vectors and return a matrix
vecEleDif <- function(vec1, vec2)
{
    #the order of arguments is vec2 - vec1
    len1 <- length(vec1);len2 <- length(vec2)
    dummy1 <- matrix(rep.int(vec1, len2), nrow=len1)
    dummy2 <- matrix(rep.int(vec2, len1), nrow=len2)
    res <- t(dummy2 - t(dummy1))
}

#Function to calculate the product of each 
#element of two different size vectors
vecEleProd <- function(vec1, vec2)
{
    #the order of the arguments is vec2 * vec1
    len1 <- length(vec1); len2 <- length(vec2)
    dummy1 <- matrix(rep.int(vec1, len2), nrow=len1)
    dummy2 <- matrix(rep.int(vec2, len1), nrow=len2)
    res <- t(dummy2 * t(dummy1))
}

ptm <- proc.time()

delta.lon <- sin(vecEleDif(mylon2, mylon1)/2)^2
delta.lan <- sin(vecEleDif(mylat2, mylat1)/2)^2
cosprod <- vecEleProd(cos(mylat1), cos(mylat2))

a <- delta.lan + (t(cosprod) * delta.lon)
b <- ifelse(sqrt(a)<1,sqrt(a),1)
c <- asin(b)
d <- 2 * c
e <- R * d
f <- c((e))

proc.time() - ptm
```

and check the output:

```
sum(f)
sum(mydistance)

all.equal(f, mydistance)

> sum(f)
[1] 647745044
> sum(mydistance)
[1] 647745044
> 
> all.equal(f, mydistance)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Since you asked me to benchmark your solution: I tested your second option (without sapply) and it took ~ 11 seconds while using my answer it took ~ 4 seconds (I'm on a different computer today)